# Inaccurate data share counts from Transient API Cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, transient

Hi I have a wp multisite where I am using the Transients API to cache social media share counts. I'm using the Answer posted here: [Caching custom social share count in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659995/caching-custom-social-share-count-in-wordpress)

Everything is working, however it is not giving me accurate share counts for all of the posts. Some have the correct share count others just show what appears to be a random number. For example a post that has 65 facebook likes only shows 1 when the Transient code is added. When I remove the Transient it shows the accurate number of shares for all of them. Any ideas of what could cause this?

Here is my code added to functions.php:

```html
class shareCount {
private $url,$timeout;
function __construct($url,$timeout=10) {
$this->url=rawurlencode($url);
$this->timeout=$timeout;
}



    function get_fb() {
    $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls='.$this->url );
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json[0]['total_count'])?intval($json[0]['total_count']):0;
    }


    private function file_get_contents_curl($url){
        // Create unique transient key
        $transientKey = 'sc_' + md5($url);

        // Check cache
        $cache = get_site_transient($transientKey); 
        
     if($cache) {
            return $cache;
        }
     
     else {
     
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        $count = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_error($ch))
        {
            die(curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Cache results for 1 hour
        set_site_transient($transientKey, $count, 60 * 60);
        return $count;
     
    }

    }


    }
```

```
Everything works if I remove if($cache) {
        return $cache;
    }
```

but then the page is really slow.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out, so figured I'd ask the experts. I've attached a screen shot comparing the post share counts with and without the Transient API so you can see the differences.

[Comparison of Share Counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNAc8.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you managed to find a solution by using transient ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this snippet and it did the work for sharecount api

```
function aesop_share_count(){

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    //$url = 'http://nickhaskins.co'; // this one used for testing to return a working result

    $url = get_permalink();

    $apiurl = sprintf('http://api.sharedcount.com/?url=%s',$url);

    $transientKey = 'AesopShareCounts'. (int) $post_id;

    $cached = get_transient($transientKey);

    if (false !== $cached) {
        return $cached;
    }

    $fetch = wp_remote_get($apiurl, array('sslverify'=>false));
    $remote = wp_remote_retrieve_body($fetch);

    if( !is_wp_error( $remote ) ) {
        $count = json_decode( $remote,true);
    }

    $twitter     = $count['Twitter'];
    $fb_like    = $count['Facebook']['like_count'];

    $total = $fb_like + $twitter;
    $out = sprintf('%s',$total);

    set_transient($transientKey, $out, 600);

    return $out;
 }
```